# Laravel migration creates migration table instead of users as expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, migration

I have created an run the following migration within my brand new Laravel project:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('name', 255);
            $table->string('email', 255);
            $table->integer('user_level');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

I would have expected it to create a `users` table with name, email, etc., but what I ended up with was a `migration` table. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you use artisan to generate the migration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
        table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->string('email', 255);
        $table->integer('user_level');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

The `migration` table is used by laravel to keep track of the migrations and rollbacks you have done.

Comment: To add to this - Schema::create is for creating a new table, Schema::table is for modifying an existing one.